# Web API silently fails for data types without a default parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I have a similar problem to this SO question: [Deserializing JSON to object with no default constructor in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360239/deserializing-json-to-object-with-no-default-constructor-in-asp-net-mvc-3) but in MVC4 and the quoted solution didn't work for me.

Essentially, If I have a class like;

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string name = "foo";
    public int age = 33;
    public MyObject(string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
}
```

and I try to return it from a Web API method;

```
    // GET api/values/5
    public **MyObject** Get(int id)
    {
        return new MyObject("Getted");
    }
```

The plumbing just throws my request on the floor. It **silently** fails with a 500 error. Now I might expect it to struggle, but I'd prefer an exception. It's not clear where this is being generated but I've tried intercepting at a number of points (FilterProvider, ValueProvider, ModelBinder) and I can't see to see which part of the plumbing is throwing it out.

This custom model binder does **not** even get called for instance;

```
public class MyObjectModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        return new MyObject("bound model");
    }
}
```

For completeness, this was registered in global.asax.cs;

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // other stuff...

        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyObject), new MyObjectModelBinder());
    }
}
```

Curiously, if I add a default constructor, it's never actually called, but the Web API plumbing just won't seem to work without it.

This **does** work (strangely);

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string name = "foo";
    public int age = 33;
    public MyObject()
    {
        throw new Exception("I am never called! But I must exist");
    }
    public MyObject(string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
}
```

I was considering raising an issue on connect.microsoft.com regarding the silent failure, but presumably there must be a workaround.

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried a Custom MediaTypeFormatter(). It calls my CanWriteType() with the relevant class 'MyObject' but it never calls me back. It still silently fails with a 500 somewhere else in the plumbing.

Comment: Does your `Get` method get called? And when you return a `string` instead of `MyObject`?

Comment: Yep. Get() gets called as you'd expect.

Comment: It appears to be a general issue. If there's an Exception thrown during serialization it subtly returns 500 too without any further description, even in debug mode.

Comment: Does the request contains the Accept: application/json header? If not, then the response will be formatted as xml(default) and it will throw because `MyObject` need to have `DataContract`and `DataMember` attributes applied to it.

Comment: Actually - that's a good call. I just tested it again and it's only the Xml serializer that chokes silently. When you say "throws" I wouldn't mind that...if I actually got it. I've long since ripped out the XML media formatter anyway because I don't want it for a slew of reasons, mostly down to what it refuses to serialise. I'll just add this quirk on to the list of reasons not to use it.

Comment: I've filed an entry on connect.microsoft.com in any case. It should at least return an exception we can handle. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757594/mvc-and-net4-5-web-api-silently-fails-for-data-types-without-a-default-parameterless-constructor

Answer (score 0):

I was trying repro your issue with the following code, but it works fine. Can you try to attach a repro?

```
class Program
{
    private const string baseAddress = "http://localhost:8080/";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        HttpSelfHostConfiguration configuration = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);
        configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default", "api/{controller}");
        HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(configuration);

        try
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();

            RunClient();
        }
        finally
        {
            server.CloseAsync().Wait();
        }
    }

    static void RunClient()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Test?id=1").Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string name = "foo";
    public int age = 33;
    public MyObject(string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
}

public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values/5
    public MyObject Get(int id)
    {
        return new MyObject("Getted");
    }
}
```

Can you please attach a repro for this?

BTW, there is a tracing package you can use to find out more information what went wrong.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing/0.3.0-rc

You can learn more about how to use this from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roncain/archive/2012/08/16/asp-net-web-api-tracing-preview.aspx

Thanks!

best, 
hongmei