# Why System.Version in JSON string does not deserialize correctly?

Tags: c#, deserialization, json.net, system.version

Context: I need to pass an object containing a large number of properties/fields (to UI Layer from Middle Tier Layer). Among this list of properties, one is of type Version which is not getting deserialized correctly from JSON string format. I have a chosen JSON format over XML as JSON serialization to string will return short string result.

Problem:
System.Version does not get deserialized correctly. I have tried two different .NET Libraries. Following are the code snippets for each:

Code Snippet 1 using [ServiceStack .NET library](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344):

```
        var version = new Version(1, 2, 3, 0);
        string reportJSON = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString<Version>(version);
        //{"Major":1,"Minor":2,"Build":3,"Revision":0,"MajorRevision":0,"MinorRevision":0}


        Version report2 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Version>(reportJSON);
        string reportJSON2 = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString<Version>(report2);
        //{"Major":0,"Minor":0,"Build":-1,"Revision":-1,"MajorRevision":-1,"MinorRevision":-1}
```

Code Snippet 2 using [Newtonsoft .NET library](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) but with same result:

```
        var version = new Version(1, 2, 3, 0);
        string reportJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(version);
        //{"Major":1,"Minor":2,"Build":3,"Revision":0,"MajorRevision":0,"MinorRevision":0}


        Version report2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Version>(reportJSON);
        string reportJSON2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(report2);
        //{"Major":0,"Minor":0,"Build":-1,"Revision":-1,"MajorRevision":-1,"MinorRevision":-1}
```

How to fix this? Or Which other JSON.NET library can work correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I deserialize to an immutable object using JavascriptSerializer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080644/can-i-deserialize-to-an-immutable-object-using-javascriptserializer)

Comment: @spender: but it works fine with string objects which are immutable.

Comment: @Monish [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2085890/1180426) is a link that explains why the `Version` class is not XML-serializable, but I'm pretty sure same mechanism applies to JSON serializers.

Answer (score 30):

The `Newtonsoft.Json` library provides a set of common converters in the `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters`namespace, including a **`VersionConverter`** you can use to serialize and deserialize `System.Version`.

**Note that you have to use the `VersionConverter`both for serialization and deserialization, though**.
That's because standard serialization would generate eg.:`{"Major":1,"Minor":2,"Build":3,"Revision":0,"MajorRevision":0,"MinorRevision":0}` while `VersionConverter`deserialization expects a simple string as in `"1.2.3"`.

So usage would be:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;  

string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(version, new VersionConverter());
Version v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Version>(s, new VersionConverter());
```

I'm not sure what's the first version of `Newtonsoft.Json`that includes that converter. Mine has it and it's 5.0.6.

Comment: Worked for me, only I had to make a little change since I'm using the DeserializeObject signature that gets the JsonSerializerSettings object:
settings.Converters.Add(new VersionConverter());
(no overload takes both settings and a collection of converters)

Answer (score 13):

The properties of the `Version` class have no setter. They just return the value of their corresponding private fields. Therefore, the deserializer is not able to change their values.

But with Json.NET you can write a custom converter class which handles the deserialization of the `Version` class.

*Beware:* This code has not been tested very well...

```
public class VersionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // default serialization
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // create a new Version instance and pass the properties to the constructor
        // (you may also use dynamics if you like)
        var dict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, int>>(reader);
        return new Version(dict["Major"], dict["Minor"], dict["Build"], dict["Revision"]);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Version);
    }
}
```

Then you have to specify that you want to use the converter:

```
var v = new Version(1, 2, 3, 4);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v);

var v2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Version>(json, new VersionConverter());
```

Json.NET decides itself whether to use one of the converters you specified. So you can always specify the converter, as shown below. Json.NET will use one of your converters if they match a type within `SomeClass`.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json, new VersionConverter());
```

Comment: What if I have a class called Userinfo and inside the class there is a variable like Dictionary<Version, string>? This var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Userinfo>(json, new VersionConverter()); doesn't work

Comment: With Json.NET 11 (maybe also earlier versions), you can just serialize/deserialize a `Version` object with the default serializer as it doesn't result in an object with `Major` and `Minor` properties etc. anymore. The default serialization result of a `Version` is now a string like `"1.2.3.4"`. And deserialization works fine. Hence using it as a key in a dictionary is not a problem. (I just tested it and it works perfectly.)

Comment: Please note that this will not work for objects with only some parts set e.g. 2.0. The oter parts are serialised as `-1` which then causes an exception at `new Version(...)`

Comment: So they changed the way it's serialized, and also what it expects to be able to deserialize, with no respect for backward compatibility.  Thus breaking anything in existence that was already serializing a Version object the old way.  Wonderful.

Comment: To clarify: As of may 2021, NET Framework builds with newtonsoft 13 can deserialize from either format.  Dotnet core builds with newtonsoft 13 can only deserialize from string format.