# Why serializing Version with JsonPropertyAttribute doesn't work?

Tags: c#, json.net, custom-attributes

I am trying to serialize an object with a static `System.Version` field:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MyObj
{
    [JsonProperty]
    private static string testStr;
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(VersionConverter))]
    private static Version ver = System.Reflection.Assembly...Version;

    // some other non-serialized fields
    // ...
}
```

I have learnt from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170386) that `Version` needs a custom converter, which I added as `ItemConverterType`. However, when I try to serialize it like this, it fails with the error: *Expected Version object value*:

```
var o = MyObj();
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(filename))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
    serializer.Serialize(file, o); // error
}
```

It works fine if I modify the attributes of the field like this:

```
public class MyObj
{
    ...
    [JsonProperty]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(VersionConverter))]
    private static Version ver = System.Reflection.Assembly...Version;
    ...
```

I am new to attributes. Can you please shed some light as to why the first one fails ? I am quite sure I am not using `Json.NET` correctly, but can't figure out why.

Comment: Seems as though it only serializes static **properties** when `[JsonProperty]` is applied.  See [Why can't JSON .Net serialize static or const member variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336597)  Change your fields to properties and you should be set to go.

Comment: @dbc thank you! note that serializing the `testStr` works fine, and the 2nd version, with the converter specified also works ok. It even works without the converter (only `JsonProperty`) for serializing, but not for deserializing. So there's something about `ItemConverterType`

Comment: 1) Really?  Does that mean the answer I linked to is obsolete?  2) [`ItemConverterType`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) allows you to specify a converter to use for *collection items*.  See [Proper way of using Newtonsoft Json ItemConverterType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639750).  Since `string` and `Version` aren't treated as collections, it's ignored.  For a converter on the property itself use `[JsonConverter]`.

Comment: 1) yes, the **static** `string` and `Version` are successfully serialized and populated on deserializing with `Json.NET` **v8.0.3**. 2) ah, I didn't realise it was for collections only. Post *2)* as an answer

Comment: Well you're right: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0UPaz9.  It was fixed in [Json.NET 6.0.4](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/6.0.4).  Maybe I'll add an answer to that old question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ItemConverterType`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) allows you to specify a converter to use for *collection items*.  See [Proper way of using Newtonsoft Json ItemConverterType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639750).  Since `string` and `Version` aren't treated as collections, it's ignored.  For a converter on the property itself use `[JsonConverter]`.

Conversely, if you had a `static List<Version> versions` it would be appropriate to use `[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(VersionConverter))]`.